Difficulty Converting Python SHT4X Tirnkey Program to C/C++
I have developed a Console Python Program that reads text data from the SHT4X Tirnkey Sensor on the Port COM7 and with a baudrate of 115200. I have attempted to create a similar Console C++ Program but this program fails to output the textual data sent from the sensors MicroPython program, via python print commands only outputting:
Serial port opened successfully.
No data received for 10 attempts. Exiting.
How do I change my C++ program to correctly read the data sent to the port by the sensor, would it be a better idea to use C instead?
Sensor MicroPython Program:
import time
import board
import adafruit_sht4x

convertToF = lambda celsius: (celsius * 9/5) + 32

i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
sht = adafruit_sht4x.SHT4x(i2c)
print("Found SHT4x with serial number", hex(sht.serial_number))

sht.mode = adafruit_sht4x.Mode.NOHEAT_HIGHPRECISION
print("Current mode is: ", adafruit_sht4x.Mode.string[sht.mode])
print()

while True:
    temperature, relative_humidity = sht.measurements
    print(f"Temperature: {convertToF(temperature):0.1f} F")
    print(f"Humidity: {relative_humidity:0.1f} %")
    print("")
    time.sleep(1)

Console Python Program
import serial #To read data from the board
import time #To wait

# Connect to the serial port
connection = serial.Serial('COM7', 115200)

# Check if the serial port is open
if connection.is_open:
    print("Serial Port Connection Established")
else:
    print("Serial Port Connection Failed")
    exit()  # Exit the program if connection fails

# Set a maximum number of iterations with no data before terminating
max_no_data_iterations = 10

# Main Program Loop
while max_no_data_iterations > 0:
    try:
        # Read from serial port
        line = connection.readline().decode().strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading from serial port: {e}")
        exit()

    # Check if serial port line is empty
    if line:
        print(line)
        max_no_data_iterations = 10  # Reset the counter if data is received
    else:
        max_no_data_iterations -= 1  # Decrement the counter if no data is received

    # Wait to prevent high CPU usage
    time.sleep(0.05)

# Print a message before exiting
print("Program terminated due to no data received.")

Console C++ Program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hSerial;
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
    int noDataCount = 0;

    // Open the serial port
    hSerial = CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\COM7", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening serial port" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Serial port opened successfully." << std::endl;

    // Set the baud rate
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) {
        std::cerr << "Error setting serial port state" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    while (true) {
        char buffer[100];
        DWORD bytesRead;

        if (ReadFile(hSerial, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL)) {
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                std::cout.write(buffer, bytesRead);
                noDataCount = 0;
            } else {
                noDataCount++;
                if (noDataCount >= 10) {
                    std::cerr << "No data received for 10 attempts. Exiting." << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Error reading from serial port" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return 0;
}

I have changed from using 115200 baudrate to 9600 baudrate without success.
I have attempted using termios.h instead of windows.h without success. I have also added and removed sleep function calls in the while loop to attempt to determine if the program was running too quickly. Based on a 5 second sleep call not producing the desired results, I do not believe that to be the case. I have also attempted to use C instead of C++ but the results were the same.

Are you sure the serial parameters you've set are correct?

Trying different APIs and different languages, adding Sleep calls is avoiding the more likely proposition that your code is wrong.  Your debug techniques  are seriously flawed.  Use your tool chain's debugger to determine what is really happening, and narrow the problem to precisely where the code fails.

timeouts is unused and ReadFile is not equivalent to readline. That is ten attempts at getting any data, not a whole line, with unknown default timeout.  You might start by removing the arbitrary noDataCount limit, and let it run indefinitely, or actually set the timeout to something sensible and known.

I am not certain if the serial parameters in the C++ Console Program are correct I've attempted changing them with no success thus far, Although I am certain the Python Program is using the correct parameters.
The SHT45 Trinkey does not appear to be compatible with any chain debugger I've found, and the issue is with the Console Application reading the data being sent to it, not with the board itself.
I have tried removing the noDataCount limit, but this did not produce the desired result. As instead the program only outputs:
Serial port opened successfully.
Any other ideas?
